# Como insertar varios registros en una misma tabla con el mismo name o id

Tags: mysql, laravel, bootstrap

Buen día compañeros tengo una duda de como insertar esto en una BD, hasta donde tengo entendido es con un array,

Este es mi formulario

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{URL::action('UsuariosController@saveenc')}}">

    {{ csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="{{ $id }}">
    <input type="text" name="pA" value="A" hidden>
    <div class="form-row">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <p><b>A. Cuando se presenta un conflicto entre personas acerca de ideas. Tiendo a estar a favor de la parte que</b></p>

        <thead>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Identifica e intenta sacar a la luz el conflicto</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="a[1a]" id="1a" required pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="5"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Expresa de la mejor manera los valores e ideales involucrados</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="a[1b]" required pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="5"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Refleja de la mejor manera mi opinión y experiencia personal</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="a[1c]" required pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="5"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">4</th>
            <td>Se aproxima a la situación con la mayor lógica y consistencia</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="a[1d]" required pattern="^[0-9]+" min="1" max="5"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">5</th>
            <td>Mejor expresa el argumento de forma más concisa y contundente.</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="a[1e]" required pattern="^[0-9]+" min="1" max="5"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
    <center><button class="btn btn-primary">Acceder</button></center>
  </form>
```

En mi controlador tengo esta parte pero me da el error de

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

Pero me lo reconoce como array esa parte donde me da error de esta manera

```
array:5a  [▼
  "1a" => "1"
  "1b" => "2"
  "1c" => "3"
  "1d" => "4"
  "1e" => "5"
]
```

y Este es el codigo que uso para insertar los valores desde mi controlador

```
public function saveenc(Request $request)
    {


      foreach($request->all() as $req){
        $encuesta = new Encuesta;
        $encuesta->id_usu = $request->get('id');
        $encuesta->pregunta = $request->get('pA');
        $encuesta->respuesta = $req['1a'];
        $encuesta->respuesta = $req['1b'];
        $encuesta->respuesta = $req['1c'];
        $encuesta->respuesta = $req['1d'];
        $encuesta->respuesta = $req['1e'];
        $encuesta->save();
        }
        return "exito";
    }
```

Y necesito que quede de esta manera en la BD

```html
-----------------------------------------
|id_enc | Pregunta | respuesta | id_usu |
-----------------------------------------
|  1    |    A     |1,4,3,2,5  |    1   |
-----------------------------------------
```

ya sea de esa manera o que cree un field para cada respuesta.

**Estoy usando Laravel 5.0 PHP 7.0, bootstrap 3.9**

Siguiendo la sugerencia de Andy Samuel, intente con

```
 $encuesta->respuesta = implode(',', $request->a);
 $encuesta->respuesta = implode(',', $request->a);
```

Y ahora me da un error de SQL

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`solvexintel`.`encuesta`, CONSTRAINT `encuesta_id_usu_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usu`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`id_usu`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `encuesta` (`id_usu`, `pregunta`, `respuesta`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (60, A, 1,2,3,4,5, 2018-08-28 18:00:46, 2018-08-28 18:00:46))

Comment: Guarda las 5 respuestas en un string [concatenandolos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php) o [con implode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php), y así mandas el string a "respuesta"

Comment: entonces si voy a cachar el array con implode() seria: $array = implode($request->a, ',');

Comment: Cambie porque vi que tenia errores conforme a la documentacion, e intente esto $encuesta->respuesta = implode(',', $request->a); pero ahora me muestra un error de base de datos, lo agrego en la pregunta

Comment: La columna respuesta es un entero? string?

Comment: Es de tipo "Number" pero ya vi porque era no habia echo refresh a la pagina y modifique antes algo en la base de datos del autoincrement y borre registros entonces creo que al insertar llave foranea o algo parecido no encontro incidencias, pero bueno ya quedo resulto, gracias por la sugerencia Samuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiendo a mi propia pregunta, el codigo me quedo de esta manera

```
        $encuesta = new Encuesta;
        $encuesta->id_usu = $request->get('id');
        $encuesta->pregunta = implode(',', $request->pa);
        $encuesta->respuesta = implode(',', $request->a);
        $encuesta->save();
```

De esta manera me guardo en la BD como solicite quedando asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a andy por el tip